# REST API Azure recovery services backup job duration in readable format

Tags: azure, powershell, rest

Using below query,

```
$restUri = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/${subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/${resourceGroup}/providers/Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults/${vaultName}/backupJobs/${jobName}?api-version=2023-02-01"
```

results returns PSCustomObject with properties/duration property as string with value as below,
sample - PT3H41M37.2007037S

it seems below method is available, not sure how to convert string to readable format tho,

```
ToDateTime Method datetime IConvertible.ToDateTime(System.IFormatProvider provider)
```

Any ideas please ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Results returns PSCustomObject with properties/duration property as string with value as below, sample - PT3H41M37.2007037S
> it seems below method is available, not sure how to convert string to readable format

To convert the duration string into a **readable** format, you can use the `TimeSpan.Parse` to parse the duration string in to a `Timespan` object, then format the `TimeSpan` object to display it in a **human-readable** format.

Here is the updated `PowerShell Script`

```
    $restUri = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/${subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/${resourceGroup}/providers/Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults/${vaultName}/backupJobs/${jobName}?api-version=2023-02-01"
    $token = Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceUrl "https://management.azure.com"
    $accessToken = $token.Token
    
    $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $restUri -Method GET -Headers @{ Authorization = "Bearer $accessToken" }
  
    $duration = $response.properties.duration
    
    $hours = [regex]::Match($duration, "(\d+)H").Groups[1].Value
    $minutes = [regex]::Match($duration, "(\d+)M").Groups[1].Value
    $seconds = [regex]::Match($duration, "(\d+(\.\d+)?)S").Groups[1].Value
    
    $timeSpan = New-TimeSpan -Hours $hours -Minutes $minutes -Seconds $seconds
    
    $result = "{0:D2} hours, {1:D2} minutes, {2:D2} seconds" -f `
        $timeSpan.Hours, $timeSpan.Minutes, $timeSpan.Seconds
    
    Write-Host "Backup Job Duration Hrs:$($timeSpan.Hours) : Minutes $($timeSpan.Minutes) : Seconds $($timeSpan.Seconds)"
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: perfect! first time having to deal with this time format, learned something new .. Thanks heaps Venkat :)

Comment: "It's good that it worked for you.